# "Hear something used" or "hear something being used"?

Tags: grammaticality, usage

Tell me please if the use *being* is optional in the following sentence?

> I never hear the word (**being**) used in day to day conversations.

If it's optional, then do people tend to drop in casual conversations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using “being” before "used" is more grammatically correct in English, most people tend to not use it in casual conversation and writing.